# Memory management for multiple Views in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, view

I'm developing an application for iOS where I need to load many views. My application needs to switch in and out the views as the user wishes. These views take up a lot of memory and I need to manage this somehow.

I was wondering if anyone could give me direction as to how to tackle this? Should I use persistant storage and write some of my views to disk? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is release them when you aren't using them anymore, and create them again when you need them (saving state if you need to restore the view in some condition). For example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We're actually making a web browser and our views are UIWebViews. When users switch between UIWebViews we don't want to reload the WebView as the page may have changed. We want the exact state that the WebView was in when the user switched away from it.

Comment: So I'm not sure if we can save the state of the UIWebView and then reload it with out reloading the page?

Comment: So what you do is download the html content, and cache it in your caches dir. Load it from your on disk cache and when the user deletes the page or refreshes the page, remove it from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you will want to unload your unused views. In addition, make sure you have your views set up for when you get a memory warning the app can handle it gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would you have any suggestions as to what I said above to the user 'jer'?

Comment: There's no built-in serialization of UIWebView. There's a couple of ways to cache just the page but not the entire state such as javascript variables. So your best bet is to keep the memory down and keep only the UIWebViews open that are critical.